# Bypass command-line cURL 2GB download limit

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, download

I am a noob in coding and only recently have started using cURL command.

I work in Windows and have downloaded cURL files from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Normally I use it for range-downloading. It works fine for all downloads below 2GB. But when I am trying to give any range above 2GB, it gives error as "416 Requested Range not satisfiable". I expect this error is coming for the 2GB limit.

This is what happens:

```
`curl --range 1048576000--1149239297 -o C:\Temp\newdownload.typ "https://dt76.energycdn.com/torrentdl/dkvOrv1Dkn5PtQncleZsAQ/1453988388/2443016/c92c744e39c125f433ce76fa87b3e043525b350b/Baahubali-The%20Beginning%20%282015%29%20-%201080p%20mHD%20-%20Blu-Ray%20-%20x264%20-%205.1%20AAC%20-%20Esubs%20%5BDDR%5D/Baahubali-The%20Beginning%20%282015%29%20-%201080p%20mHD%20-%20Blu-Ray%20-%20x264%20-%205.1%20AAC%20-%20Esubs%20%5BDDR%5D.mkv"`
```

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100   212  100   212    0     0     82      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    82

The 212 bytes file which got downloaded contains the following:

```
`<html>
<head><title>416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
`
```

I love cURL as a downloader but this limit is killing me. Plz help.

Comment: From what it looks like, the error is not related to curl but is related to nginx on the server you're trying to download a file from.

Comment: this is a server side message

Answer (score 2):

This is a server-side error, curl has no problems with file sizes up to 64bit on modern operating systems.

But your range looks wrong, you have two dashes (minuses) in the range string and that might cause the server to refuse you (possibly it considers the second number to be negative). Try `--range 1048576000-1149239297`.

Use curl's `-v` option to see exactly what it sends in its request and what server response headers it gets.

Finally: your example command line here is still below 2GB in both values...

Comment: Has Windows 2GB+ file support been merged into main yet? (re: https://github.com/bagder/curl/pull/451 and the parallel https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/pull/31).

Comment: That's >2GB **SFTP** on Windows support, which has its own special restriction. It is not a generic 2GB problem. It is a problem related to the libssh2 API. And no, that's not been fixed yet since libssh2 has not yet had a release with its improved API.